# Updating from Ruby 1.8.7 to Ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Currently I have Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.8. Is it possible to update ruby so that I do not have to re-install all the gems again?

Comment: Yes. Write a ruby 1.9 script to install all of the gems you had with 1.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're best bet is using [RVM](https://rvm.io/), it will let you have multiple versions of Ruby and gems per directory or project.

Comment: Yeah, RVM is by far the best way to manage Ruby versions and associated gems.

Answer (score 0):

No - you will have to install the gems again per Ruby. RVM aids this in that you can import a gemset file, but ultimately - you will end up installing the gems again.

See https://rvm.io/gemsets/importing/ for more details

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that if you don't like rvm cause of the way it overwrites cd and gem, you can use rbenv/ruby build tool just wanting to point out that there are more options now.  The github repo is here https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Answer (score -1):

Ruby is currently on version 1.9.1, which sports a new JIT VM, providing much improved performance when compared to Ruby 1.8. The good news is that Rails, as of version 2.3.2, fully supports Ruby 1.9.1. The bad news is that several Ruby libraries have not been updated for Ruby 1.9.1. Please refer to [IsItRuby19](http://isitruby19.com/) to see a list of currently supported Ruby 1.9.1 libraries.